Error when building gem5 caused by not loading local python packages
Following my course requirements, I would like to install gem5 (v23.0.0.1) on my Ubuntu 22.04 computer. Using command scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j 1 (only using 1 thread is for problem exhibition purpose), I got an error saying
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Mkdir("/home/chenshulun/桌面/work/AI+X/gem5/build/X86/gem5.build")
Checking for linker -Wl,--as-needed support... yes
Checking for compiler -gz support... yes
Checking for linker -gz support... yes
Info: Using Python config: python3-config
Checking for C header file Python.h... yes
Checking Python version... 3.10.12
Checking for accept(0,0,0) in C++ library None... yes
Checking for zlibVersion() in C++ library z... yes
Checking for C library tcmalloc_minimal... yes
Building in /home/chenshulun/桌面/work/AI+X/gem5/build/X86
Variables file(s) /home/chenshulun/桌面/work/AI+X/gem5/build/X86/gem5.build/variables or /home/chenshulun/桌面/work/AI+X/gem5/build/variables/X86 not found,
  using defaults in /home/chenshulun/桌面/work/AI+X/gem5/build_opts/X86
Checking for C header file fenv.h... yes
Checking for C header file png.h... yes
Checking for clock_nanosleep(0,0,NULL,NULL) in C library None... yes
Checking for C header file valgrind/valgrind.h... no
Checking for pkg-config package hdf5-serial... yes
Checking for H5Fcreate("", 0, 0, 0) in C library hdf5... yes
Checking for H5::H5File("", 0) in C++ library hdf5_cpp... yes
Checking for C header file linux/if_tun.h... yes
Checking for shm_open("/test", 0, 0) in C library None... yes
Checking for C header file linux/kvm.h... yes
Checking for timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, NULL, NULL) in C library None... yes
Checking for member exclude_host in struct perf_event_attr...yes
Checking for pkg-config package protobuf... yes
Checking for GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION in C++ library protobuf... yes
Checking for backtrace_symbols_fd((void *)1, 0, 0) in C library None... yes
Checking size of struct kvm_xsave ... yes
Checking whether __i386__ is declared... no
Checking whether __x86_64__ is declared... yes
Checking for compiler -Wno-self-assign-overloaded support... yes
Checking for linker -Wno-free-nonheap-object support... yes
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
 [     CXX] src/python/gem5py.cc -> X86/python/gem5py.pyo
 [    LINK]  -> X86/gem5py
 [EMBED PY] src/base/Graphics.py -> X86/base/Graphics.py.cc
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pybind11::error_already_set'
terminate called recursively
Aborted (core dumped)
scons: *** [build/X86/base/Graphics.py.cc] Error 134
scons: building terminated because of errors.


For reference purposes, here's all my python packages printed by pip list:
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- ----------------
apturl                             0.5.2
bcrypt                             3.2.0
beautifulsoup4                     4.10.0
blinker                            1.4
Brlapi                             0.8.3
certifi                            2020.6.20
cfgv                               3.4.0
chardet                            4.0.0
click                              8.0.3
colorama                           0.4.4
command-not-found                  0.3
cryptography                       3.4.8
cupshelpers                        1.0
dbus-python                        1.2.18
debugpy                            1.6.0
defer                              1.0.6
distlib                            0.3.8
distro                             1.7.0
distro-info                        1.1+ubuntu0.2
duplicity                          0.8.21
fasteners                          0.14.1
filelock                           3.15.4
future                             0.18.2
gyp                                0.1
html5lib                           1.1
httplib2                           0.20.2
identify                           2.6.0
idna                               3.3
importlib-metadata                 4.6.4
jeepney                            0.7.1
keyring                            23.5.0
language-selector                  0.1
launchpadlib                       1.10.16
lazr.restfulclient                 0.14.4
lazr.uri                           1.0.6
lockfile                           0.12.2
louis                              3.20.0
lxml                               4.8.0
macaroonbakery                     1.3.1
Mako                               1.1.3
MarkupSafe                         2.0.1
mercurial                          6.1.1
monotonic                          1.6
more-itertools                     8.10.0
mypy                               0.942
mypy-extensions                    0.4.3
netifaces                          0.11.0
nodeenv                            1.9.1
oauthlib                           3.2.0
olefile                            0.46
paramiko                           2.9.3
pexpect                            4.8.0
Pillow                             9.0.1
pip                                22.0.2
platformdirs                       4.2.2
pre-commit                         2.20.0
protobuf                           3.12.4
psutil                             5.9.0
ptyprocess                         0.7.0
pybind11                           2.13.1
pycairo                            1.20.1
pycups                             2.0.1
pydot                              1.4.2
Pygments                           2.11.2
PyGObject                          3.42.1
PyJWT                              2.3.0
pymacaroons                        0.13.0
PyNaCl                             1.5.0
pyparsing                          2.4.7
PyQt5-Qt5                          5.15.2
PyQt5-sip                          12.10.1
pyRFC3339                          1.1
python-apt                         2.4.0+ubuntu3
python-dateutil                    2.8.1
python-debian                      0.1.43+ubuntu1.1
pytz                               2022.1
pyxdg                              0.27
PyYAML                             5.4.1
QtPy                               2.0.1
reportlab                          3.6.8
requests                           2.25.1
SCons                              4.0.1
SecretStorage                      3.3.1
setuptools                         59.6.0
six                                1.16.0
soupsieve                          2.3.1
systemd-python                     234
toml                               0.10.2
tomli                              1.2.2
tqdm                               4.64.1
typed-ast                          1.4.3
types-aiofiles                     0.1
types-annoy                        1.17
types-appdirs                      1.4
types-atomicwrites                 1.4
types-aws-xray-sdk                 2.8
types-babel                        2.9
types-backports-abc                0.5
types-backports.ssl-match-hostname 3.7
types-beautifulsoup4               4.10
types-bleach                       4.1
types-boto                         2.49
types-braintree                    4.11
types-cachetools                   4.2
types-caldav                       0.8
types-certifi                      2020.4
types-characteristic               14.3
types-chardet                      4.0
types-click                        7.1
types-click-spinner                0.1
types-colorama                     0.4
types-commonmark                   0.9
types-contextvars                  0.1
types-croniter                     1.0
types-cryptography                 3.3
types-dataclasses                  0.1
types-dateparser                   1.0
types-DateTimeRange                0.1
types-decorator                    0.1
types-Deprecated                   1.2
types-docopt                       0.6
types-docutils                     0.17
types-editdistance                 0.5
types-emoji                        1.2
types-entrypoints                  0.3
types-enum34                       1.1
types-filelock                     3.2
types-first                        2.0
types-Flask                        1.1
types-freezegun                    1.1
types-frozendict                   0.1
types-futures                      3.3
types-html5lib                     1.1
types-httplib2                     0.19
types-humanfriendly                9.2
types-ipaddress                    1.0
types-itsdangerous                 1.1
types-JACK-Client                  0.1
types-Jinja2                       2.11
types-jmespath                     0.10
types-jsonschema                   3.2
types-Markdown                     3.3
types-MarkupSafe                   1.1
types-mock                         4.0
types-mypy-extensions              0.4
types-mysqlclient                  2.0
types-oauthlib                     3.1
types-orjson                       3.6
types-paramiko                     2.7
types-Pillow                       8.3
types-polib                        1.1
types-prettytable                  2.1
types-protobuf                     3.17
types-psutil                       5.8
types-psycopg2                     2.9
types-pyaudio                      0.2
types-pycurl                       0.1
types-pyfarmhash                   0.2
types-Pygments                     2.9
types-PyMySQL                      1.0
types-pyOpenSSL                    20.0
types-pyRFC3339                    0.1
types-pysftp                       0.2
types-pytest-lazy-fixture          0.6
types-python-dateutil              2.8
types-python-gflags                3.1
types-python-nmap                  0.6
types-python-slugify               5.0
types-pytz                         2021.1
types-pyvmomi                      7.0
types-PyYAML                       5.4
types-redis                        3.5
types-requests                     2.25
types-retry                        0.9
types-selenium                     3.141
types-Send2Trash                   1.8
types-setuptools                   57.4
types-simplejson                   3.17
types-singledispatch               3.7
types-six                          1.16
types-slumber                      0.7
types-stripe                       2.59
types-tabulate                     0.8
types-termcolor                    1.1
types-toml                         0.10
types-toposort                     1.6
types-ttkthemes                    3.2
types-typed-ast                    1.4
types-tzlocal                      0.1
types-ujson                        0.1
types-vobject                      0.9
types-waitress                     0.1
types-Werkzeug                     1.0
types-xxhash                       2.0
typing-extensions                  3.10.0.2
ubuntu-drivers-common              0.0.0
ubuntu-pro-client                  8001
ufw                                0.36.1
unattended-upgrades                0.1
urllib3                            1.26.5
usb-creator                        0.3.7
virtualenv                         20.26.3
wadllib                            1.3.6
webencodings                       0.5.1
wheel                              0.37.1
xdg                                5
xkit                               0.0.0
zipp                               1.0.0

To figure out what was happening, I tried the command scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j 1 --verbose (with folder build deleted beforehand) and the last lines of the log says
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o build/X86/python/gem5py.pyo -c -std=c++17 -gz -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wundef -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Iext/pybind11/include -Isrc -Iinclude -Iext -I/usr/include/python3.10 -Iext/nomali/include -Iext/libfdt -Iext/iostream3 -Iext/libelf -Iext/softfloat -Iext/fputils/include -Iext/drampower/src -Iext/pybind11/include -Isrc -Iinclude -Iext -I/usr/include/python3.10 -I/usr/include/hdf5/serial -Iext/googletest/googletest/include -Iext/googletest/googlemock/include -Ibuild/X86 -Ibuild/X86/systemc/ext -Ibuild/X86/arch/arm/fastmodel/examples/SystemCExport/Common/include -Ibuild/X86/arch/arm/fastmodel/include -Ibuild/X86/arch/arm/fastmodel/include/fmruntime -Ibuild/X86/arch/arm/fastmodel/include/fmruntime/eslapi -Ibuild/X86/arch/arm/fastmodel/Iris/include -Isrc/systemc/ext/systemc_home/include -Ibuild/X86/arch/arm/fastmodel/AMBA-PV/include -Ibuild/X86/arch/arm/fastmodel/PL330_DMAC/gcc/gen -Ibuild/X86/arch/arm/fastmodel/CortexR52/x1/gcc/gen -Ibuild/X86/arch/arm/fastmodel/CortexR52/x2/gcc/gen -Ibuild/X86/arch/arm/fastmodel/CortexR52/x3/gcc/gen -Ibuild/X86/arch/arm/fastmodel/CortexR52/x4/gcc/gen -Ibuild/X86/arch/arm/fastmodel/CortexA76/x1/gcc/gen -Ibuild/X86/arch/arm/fastmodel/CortexA76/x2/gcc/gen -Ibuild/X86/arch/arm/fastmodel/CortexA76/x3/gcc/gen -Ibuild/X86/arch/arm/fastmodel/CortexA76/x4/gcc/gen -Ibuild/X86/arch/arm/fastmodel/GIC/gcc/gen src/python/gem5py.cc
g++ -o build/X86/gem5py -z origin -Wl,--as-needed -gz build/X86/python/gem5py.pyo -L/usr/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.10 -lcrypt -ldl -lm -lz
"/home/chenshulun/桌面/work/AI+X/gem5/build/X86/gem5py" "build_tools/marshal.py" "build/X86/base/Graphics.py.cc" "src/base/Graphics.py" "m5.objects.Graphics" "/home/chenshulun/桌面/work/AI+X/gem5/src/base/Graphics.py"
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pybind11::error_already_set'
terminate called recursively
Aborted (core dumped)
scons: \*\*\* \[build/X86/base/Graphics.py.cc\] Error 134
scons: building terminated because of errors.

It seems that something wrong happened during the execution of build/X86/gem5py. In fact, directly running this command produces error log saying
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pybind11::error_already_set'
    what():  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blob'

At:
    build_tools/marshal.py(57): \<module\>

Aborted (core dumped)

The most likely reason for the problem it that gem5py somehow fails to load local packages. However, I don't know whether that's really the cause, nor do I know how to fixed it.
